# User input validation only numbers and letter allowed

Tags: php, validation

I have a form where users enter in car registrations so I only want to allow numbers and letters?

```
if(preg_match("/(A-Za-z0-9]+/", $to)){

$errors[] = "Only use numbers and letters please";}
```

get the error...

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 12 in /homepages/28/d420353834/htdocs/regupdate.php on line 84
```

So I am guessing I have got it wrong.

Comment: I'd have thought that the message saying that there's a missing ), and the fact that your regexp has an opening ( without a closing ), and a closing ] without an opening [ was pretty obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `[` before the `A`, and a `)` before the final `/` in your regex. Should look like:

```
if (preg_match("/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/", $to)) {
```

Also, if you're only testing for boolean, and not collecting the matches, you could omit the `()` entirely.

Comment: I was waiting who is going to be the first to spot **both** errors. You where 1st ;)

Comment: does this regexp exclude strings containing non-alphanumeric chars?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(preg_match("/([A-Za-z0-9])+/", $to)){
    // action ...       
}
```

You're missing `[` at start and at the end `)` in regexp

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
if(preg_match("/([A-Za-z0-9])+/", $to))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think other answers regexps return true even if your string contains a single alphanumeric char in a string containing ALSO non-alphanumeric chars. (Try with "???alpha!!123" for exaple)

If you want to ensure your string contains ONLY alphanumeric chars, try this code:

```
if (preg_match("/^([[:alnum:]])*$/", $to))
{
    $errors[] = "Only use numbers and letters please";
}
```